# Laravel: Conditionally call laravel accesor when I want in controller?

Tags: php, laravel

in my laravel app controller I want to retrieve chats where a user participates, I append user id to the request itself and then in controlelr I create a laravel model accesor called chat_receiver, if I append this accesor everytime I retrieve the chat model I get the chat_receiver too, that way I don't retrive both chat participants (user_id,receiver_id), howver I DON'T ALWAYS WANT to get accesor.

So the question, is there a way to call the accesor in controller whenever I need instead of appending it, like how I can use Model::with([ 'relationship ])...

My accessor on Chat Model:

```
public function getChatReceiverAttribute()
    {
        $request = resolve(Request::class);
        $user_id = $request->get('user_id', false);

        if($user_id)
        {
            if($user_id == $this->user->id)
            {
                //return $this->receiver;
                
                return 
                [
                    'id' => $this->receiver->id,
                    'name' => $this->receiver->name,
                    'lat' => $this->receiver->lat,
                    'lng' => $this->receiver->lng,
                    'images' => $this->receiver->images,
                    'sexuality' => $this->receiver->sexuality,
                    'birthYear' => $this->receiver->birthYear,
                    'birthMonth' => $this->receiver->birthMonth,
                    'birthDay' => $this->receiver->birthDay,
                    'gender' => $this->receiver->gender,
                    'fcm_token' => $this->user->fcm_token,
                    'languageCode' => $this->user->languageCode,
                    'mood' => $this->user->mood,
                    'description' => $this->user->description,
                ];
                
            }
            else
            {
                //return $this->user;
                
                return 
                [
                    'id' => $this->user->id,
                    'name' => $this->user->name,
                    'lat' => $this->user->lat,
                    'lng' => $this->user->lng,
                    'images' => $this->user->images,
                    'sexuality' => $this->user->sexuality,
                    'birthYear' => $this->user->birthYear,
                    'birthMonth' => $this->user->birthMonth,
                    'birthDay' => $this->user->birthDay,
                    'gender' => $this->user->gender,
                    'fcm_token' => $this->user->fcm_token,
                    'languageCode' => $this->user->languageCode,
                    'mood' => $this->user->mood,
                    'description' => $this->user->description,
                ];
                
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return [];
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you use your accessor in your controller?

Comment: In the model I add chatreceiver attribute to appends array, and it gets added automatically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of adding it to the appends array. You can add it programatically when you need it. If you look at the code for the Model trait [HasAttributes.php](https://github.com/illuminate/database/blob/master/Eloquent/Concerns/HasAttributes.php#L2095). You can see you can add appended attributes on demand. For this is used the higher order function collection helper.

```
Model::where('something', 'something')
    ->get()
    ->each
    ->append(['chat_receiver']);
```

Adding it for a single model would be.

```
$model->append(['chat_receiver']);
```